# Make an app wirelessly connect to an Xbox 360 (ala Connect360, Rivet, Vuze)

Tags: api, reverse-engineering, media, wireless, xbox360

Programs like Connect360, Rivet, and Vuze can wirelessly connect to an Xbox 360 and share videos and pictures on your Mac with it. How do they do this?

The simplest answer would be that Microsoft offers some sort of API, but I haven't been able to find one. Furthermore, the programs I listed have wildly different feature sets, and Microsoft doesn't seem like the type of company to offer an API for this type of thing.

Based on all that, I feel like it's more likely some sort of reverse engineering. Does anyone have any insight on how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xbox 360 needs a UPnP AV server with an extra custom UPnP service called X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar.

Comment: I haven't started working on this yet, but this is definitely the best answer I've gotten. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I recommend looking at the Platinum UPnP SDK. It is cross platform C++ library and supports the Xbox extra service out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The Xbox connects to them, not vice-versa, and the protocol is called UPnP.